# manual facebook login process with flutter

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, flutter, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement facebook login with flutter using Django Rest Framework as the backend with `rest-social-auth` dependency for social login. This dependency doesn't take the access_token, which the facebook sdk provides by default but it takes the code, as stated in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/#login. The problem I'm having is that now, I have to show the facebook login popup by myself to the user and wait for a response from backend.

the url used is something like:

`https://www.facebook.com/v3.3/dialog/oauth
?client_id=1234567890
&redirect_uri=https://example.com:8000/redirect/uri/`

Currently, I'm trying to do this:

1. User taps on 'login with facebook' button (it's just a common button with `onPress` method)
2. App shows popup with facebook auth (don't know how to implement this)
3. If user accepts, then facebook will return an authentication code to backend
4. Backend exchanges that code (via rest-social-auth) for an access token, gets user data and authenticates her.
5. Backend sends message back to mobile client with jwt token.

So.. Here are some questions:

1. Should the redirect_uri be a backend endpoint or should it be sent back to mobile and the mobile sends a request to backend to exchange that code for a JWT?

   If the redirect_uri should be backend's then how does it keep track on how to return a response to the client?

   In case the redirect_uri is mobile, how does it handle the response? Or I'm understanding everything wrong and mobile doesn't use the url approach with redirect_uri?
2. If my approach is correct, then how can I invoke the facebook authenticate popup from flutter and capture the response sent by backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to achieve your goal you need to actually implement following pipeline:

App gets auth_token -> sends it to backend -> backend does magic -> returns JWT token.

1. Use `flutter_facebook_login` on device to get `access_token` from Facebook.
2. Write custom pipeline for processing token, getting data from Facebook and creating new user or getting JWT token on backend (like [article](https://medium.com/@chimamireme/writing-a-client-server-token-based-facebook-authentication-with-django-rest-framework-451d79f3dfc) suggests).

or

2. Add `django-rest-framework-social-oauth2` as a dependency and then you will be able to use `access_token` to get your JWT token. You can reference [medium article](https://medium.com/@katherinekimetto/simple-facebook-social-login-using-django-rest-framework-e2ac10266be1) for guidance.